# Implement data driven Swing components cleanly

Tags: java, swing, data-driven

I have inherited a Java Swing data maintenance app.

There is a user administration module which has the main user attributes on 
the main JPanel.
In a subsidiary JTabbedPane there are master detail relationships maintained.
e.g. the groups that user is a member of and the organisations that a user can be associated with.
I need to be able to cross validate such that the organisation pane will only be accessible if the user is a member of a particular group.

What is best way to achieve this without getting the Swing UI code and the data access and management code tied together?

I can see the need for more of this data driven component management so a generic way
of accomplishing this is what I am looking for ideally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and "services". One such service is "canUserAccessOrgPane()"

The UI gets the bean which implements the service injected without any knowledge where it comes from.

The bean has no idea in which parts of the code it is used.

The config of the DI framework will connect the two.

Comment: Thanks, I have had a delve into the subject and can see a fairly extensive rewrite coming on.